# Is there a command only clear terminal to previous mark like cmd+L does in macos?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Basically I want to look back to my previous console output from time to time, but the cleanliness of console is also important to me. So if I wrongly output something to console, I want just remove that part.

something like this but ignore the command in the picture.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON6Vx.png]

Let’s say I already have something output by previous command to console like yellow part in picture. I think this most recent part is distracting and want to remove it. How can I only clear the yellow part and leave green part and all output before green part as they were?

Macos does have a shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to achieve this, however in ubuntu that actually just scroll your output up. While clear command would remove all ouput.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same question, don't know any terminal does support this feature.